# NodeJS get values from SQL query

Tags: node.js

I have https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql module.

They show examples how to use it when multiple rows are expected, but I couldn't find one example showing how to fetch a single result into a variable.

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1
```

how do I fetch this into `sqlValues` variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the callback function of the `.query` method, the second parameter contains an array containing the rows returned from your query. No matter how many are returned, these can be indexed just as an array.

Thus, in the callback function to get the single expected result, you can use `rows[0]`.

In your specific instance, to assign the returned `name` field to the `sqlValues` variable, you can use a simple assignment: `sqlValues = rows[0].name`

Answer (score 0):

You can see the code below which connects to sql and fetches data.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'your-username',
      password : 'your-password',
      database : 'wordpress',
    }
);

connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log('Post Titles: ', rows[i].yourcolumnname);
    }
});

connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this code like this … (more simple)

```
var queryString = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err
     res.send(rows)
     console.log(rows)//this 
});

connection.end();
```